# What's size of upgrading from desktop? in update manager app?

Tags: upgrade

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and wanna to update to 12.04 LTS.
I want to know the size of upgrade from my desktop PC.

Please, tell me that

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend what or how much files you need to Upgrade. Suppose you have Open Office and you have never Upgraded it to the latest version, then On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Upgrade, it will add an extra burden of Upgrading Open Office.

Comment: Go for a fresh install of 12.04 if possible.

Comment: I want to upgrade with only bases detail Ubuntu 32bit OS,my open office is old too